# amazon web server guider for beginner

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to open a web application server on the amazon AWS.
can someone guide me which services I would need to run :

- .net web application.
- office 2013.

I'm new in that so please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EC2 Instances (virtual private servers) for that. Check out the getting started for windows guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_GetStarted.html

And take a free lab at http://run.qwiklabs.com